# Is there a method to set up S3 replication rules when OAI is enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set one replication rule from an AWS account to another. I have configured the AWS IAM role and the destination bucket policy, but once I want to test if the replication works, I get the replication status 'FAILED'. The destination bucket is configured to restrict access to only CloudFront using OAI. I have configured multiple statements for the bucket permission:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity OAI_ID"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination/*"
        },
        {
         "Sid":"Set permissions for objects",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::source-bucket-acct-ID:role/source-acct-IAM-role"
         },
         "Action":["s3:ReplicateObject", "s3:ReplicateDelete"],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::destination/*"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"Set permissions on bucket",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::source-bucket-acct-ID:role/source-acct-IAM-role"
         },
         "Action":["s3:List*", "s3:GetBucketVersioning", "s3:PutBucketVersioning"],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::destination"
      }
    ]
}
```

This implementation works if I don't have OAI enabled.

Is there a method to set up S3 replication rules when OAI is enabled?

Comment: The policy as shown doesn't appear to deny any form of access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the S3 policy is a way to allow/deny access to the bucket. Just put needed permissions for replication on source and destination bucket and you are good to go